# How to debug which file is causing errors in laravel 5.1

Tags: debugging, laravel-5.1, artisan-migrate

After creating multiple migrations I started editing these and sometimes testing them out. All was working well untill I tried the use of [foreign keys](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/25/creating-a-hasmany-relation-in-laravel-5/) taken from this example.

For some reason this wasn't working for me, so I decided to remove everything with foreign. Now when I run a `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  syntax error,
>   unexpected ';'

I know it's related to one of the migrations I edited, but how can I quickly find it without going through all the migrations I created.

My question isn't about where my problem is (so my exact code isn't necessary), but how to debug efficiently?

**EDIT:**

I just tried `php artisan:rollback` and that works.

**EDIT #2:**

I just 'fixed' my problem, but would like to know for future reference how to debug faster.

Comment: maybe an editor can help you achieve this!? like phpStorm!

Comment: You mean an ide? I'm already using an editor (notepad++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the artisan command with verbose output

```
php artisan -vvv migrate
```

This will reveal more information about the syntax error.

Edit: from my comment,

You can quickly scan for syntax issues with the following cli command (unix only)

```
find -L database/migrations -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l
```

For users on windows using **git bash**:

```
find database/migrations -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l
```

Comment: still the same output nothing more or less

Comment: in that case, try running php lint over your directory
`find -L database/migrations -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l`

Comment: this is for unix/linux rigth? I'm using xampp on windows

Comment: I edited my question to reflect that, sorry for not adding it in the first place

Comment: there's probably a way to do that via the windows cli, but i'd suggest using https://www.cygwin.com/ to emulate a nix* terminal on your windows machine :)

Comment: would a git bash work? I never really liked cygwin, but for this project I needed some windows dll's to run, so I am stuck on windows

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, so i'm not sure. Try it :)

Comment: just tried it, it gives an error: find: invalid predicate '-L'

Comment: after removing the -L it works in git bash, what does the -L do?

Comment: It's to deal with symbolic links. In your case removing it is fine.